# Strange type mismatch in C++

Tags: c++, types, constants

I need some help here, how is such a type mismatch even possible? 
When I substitute everything in, it is exactly the same type including
constness.

```
cgVertex3D.cpp:33: error: no matching function for call to 
std::vector<Polygon3D*, std::allocator<Polygon3D*> >::push_back(const Polygon3D*&)

/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:733:
note: candidates are: 

void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = Polygon3D*, _Alloc = std::allocator<Polygon3D*>]
<near match>
```

Comment: Are you passing a value, perhaps (as opposed to a pointer)? Show us the code.

Comment: looks like you are trying to push a const* onto a vector of non-const pointers

Comment: Can you show us the code? The compiler doesn't think it's exactly the same type including constness; it thinks you're pushing a pointer-to-const onto a vector of pointer-to-nonconst.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `_Tp` that is `const`, and in this case `_Tp` is a pointer.  So the substitution for `const _Tp` will actually result in `Polygon3D *const`, not `const Polygon3D *`, hence the mismatch.